# Can I use Sitecore Forms without jQuery?

Tags: sitecore-forms

Can I use Sitecore Forms without JQuery? I mean, I can see how to make it so JQuery wont output on the page, but will it still work? I see that I will need to make my own validation. Anything other than that?

Comment: I understood from a colleague who looked into it that it would not be so much work to convert the jQuery code required for Sitecore Forms in to mondden JavaScript. But if you would rewrite the required code, you are probably on your own regarding support.

Comment: I agree with Serge, it should be doable, also you could look at the JSS implementation https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/forms

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the scripts defined `\sitecore modules\Web\ExperienceForms\scripts\`, besides the validation you'll have to also handle these areas:

- the ajax requests if the form is set in design as Ajax enabled
- rewrite the existing code if performance tracking is enabled on the form
- the different types of actions on the buttons
- rendering of the fields, if you take a look at `Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates` the Date field is using jquery for date selection
- I would say the more complex one would be to handle all of the conditions that the editors can select on the fields